# list index out of range-python

Tags: python, list, indexing, window

I'm trying to make an hangman game where you can type a specific word into it.

I came across a problem when trying to make a code which count the number of same letters in the word. For example, `'taste'` will have two `t`s.

The program would count the letter which will be used for mathematical sums so the letter can be entered twice but no more.

I came across the list index is out of range problem in the code below.

```
def nolettercheck():

    global list45 #list of variable within code (so they can be accessed)
    global list1
    global countonce
    global count0
    global count1
    global count2
    global count3
    global count4
    global count5
    global count6
    global count7
    global count8
    global count9
    if len(list1) == 1: #makes sure list is in range
        if list1.count(list1[0]) > 1: """count how many letter in word and if above 1 it continues
                                         (although it doesn't work perfectly yet BTW do not spoil 
                                          this answer for me unless
                                         you have to)."""
            count0 = list1.count(list1[0])#create variable for number of same letters
            list45.insert(0,list1[0])#insert the letter into another list for comparison
    if len(list1) == 2 or len(list1) < 2: """repeats with next letter until
                                             similar statement =false"""
        if list1.count(list1[1]) > 1:
            count1 = list1.count(list1[1])
            list45.insert(1,list1[1])
    if len(list1) == 3 or len(list1) < 3:
        if list1.count(list1[2]) > 1:
            count2 = list1.count(list1[2])
            list45.insert(2,list1[2])
    if len(list1) == 4 or len(list1) < 4:
        if list1.count(list1[3]) > 1:
            count3 = list1.count(list1[3])
            list45.insert(3,list1[3])
    if len(list1) == 5 or len(list1) < 5:
        if list1.count(list1[4]) > 1:
            count4 = list1.count(list1[4])
            list45.insert(4,list1[4])
    if len(list1) == 6 or len(list1) < 6:
        if list1.count(list1[5]) > 1:
            count5 = list1.count(list1[5])
            list45.insert(5,list1[5])
    if len(list1) == 7 or len(list1) < 7:
        if list1.count(list1[6]) > 1:
            count6 = list1.count(list1[6])
            list45.insert(6,list1[6])
```

The code continues so it can do up to a ten letter word. This code is suppose to store the no of letter into a variable (which will be turned into a list later down the line although I might change that further on). It should also store the letter (if there is more than one letter).

The error specifically focuses on similar lines to `if list1.count(list[6]) > 1:`.

I did come across this error before and `if len(list1) == 7 or len(list1) <7:` worked (as it stopped checking for imaginary values in the list). So I am quite befuddled about this.

Comment: Ouch, this is painful. You should really consider making a list of 10 counts instead of 10 separate variables, a loop over `range(1, 8)` instead of copying and pasting the same code 7 times, and most likely using a more appropriate data structure than a list that you have to keep calling `count` and `insert` on…

Comment: Also, `len(list1) == 7 or len(list1) < 7` can be written as `len(list1) <= 7`.

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate a little more on what you are trying to achieve from this? From what I understand you simply want a letter count from a word (yet limit it to 2?). I believe there will be a much simpler way to do this as what you have here looks extremely inefficient.

Comment: Anyway, can you post a complete, but stripped-down, program (and input) that demonstrates the problem, and post the exception and traceback instead of trying to describe it? See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help for some guidance.

Comment: I did try <= but it kept running into a syntax error as if I should do <== but that obviously doesn't exist.

Comment: I was considering eliminating the variables and converting it straight into a list but I want to make sure it works before shorting or eliminating any code (unless needed). I tried to limit it to each character so I can get the number of each character, I am changing it as we speak as it really doesn't work anyway.

Comment: BTW I would of showed you the whole code but as you said, it not very efficient yet and very long winded. Its almost complete once I fix this error

Comment: BTW thank you for commenting!!!

Comment: oh wait <= is working, I just had it the wrong way around. My bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a way to get a dictionary of letter counts from a word. there are more 'pythonic' ways of doing this but if you're just getting started, this may help you out.

```
a = 'somestring'
letter_count_dict = {}
for letter in set(a):
    letter_count_dict[letter] = a.count(letter)
```

the distinct letters in the word are

```
set(a) #set takes the distinct values.  If you want a list of distinct values, an easy way to do it is list(set(a)) but since sets are iterable you don't usually need to do this.
```

and given a letter, l, the number of times it occurs is

```
letter_count_dict[l]  #if l='s', then this would output 2
```

once you have the counts, you can choose what to do with them...loop and find the ones with greater than one occurrence, etc..  good luck.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to avoid making an entire dictionary for each letter but it probably slightly more efficient then what I have now.